# After binding my mouse click to options in tkinter, I want to be able to use the options selected to write an if statement

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I want to use the `listbox` function to do a calculation if one of the options is selected. I tried returning the function and storing it in a variable but it did not work.

```py
def miler():
    bolt = float(put.get())
    ans = bolt * 1.689
    kilo.config(text=f"{ans}")


miles = Label(text="Miles")
miles.grid(column=2, row=0)

put = Entry()
put.grid(column=1, row=0)

equal = Label(text="is equal to")
equal.grid(column=0, row=1)

kilo = Label(text=0)
kilo.grid(column=1, row=1)

unit = Label(text="km")
unit.grid(column=2, row=1)

calc = Button(text="Calculate", command=miler, )
calc.grid(column=1, row=2)


def listbox_used(event):
    law = listbox.get(listbox.curselection())
    listbox = Listbox(height=3)
    quantity = ["Celsius", "Kilogram", "Meter/second"]
    for item in quantity:
        listbox.insert(quantity.index(item), item)
    listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", listbox_used)

    listbox.grid(column=0, row=0)
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: There are a few problems. The 'law' variable is local to the listbox_used callback. So it cannot be reached by your 'if law' statement. One solution may be to declare law as 'global'. Second, the statements after mainloop() must be moved into miler(). I can say more but I will refrains because I do not understand how Celsius and kilos relate to distance.

Comment: Post a [mre]. The current code is not equivalent to the original one. I guess this happened because you didn't post a [mre]. @Ian Thompson, be careful when editing the original code. In most cases, it's not recommended.